Questions about FFT
I have a few questions about the FFT, to solidify my knowledge in this algorithm.
Here is an example of the pseudocode of FFT:
\begin{array}{ll}
\textbf{Algorithm:} & \text{FFT} \\
\text{Input:} & \text{Array } A \text{ of length } n \\
\text{Output:} & \text{Array } Y \text{ containing the FFT of } A \\
\text{} & \\
\textbf{FFT}(A, n) & \\
n & = \text{length of } A \\
\text{if } n = 1 \text{ then} & \\
\quad \text{return } A & \\
\omega_n & = e^{-2\pi i / n} \\
\omega & = 1 \\
a_e & = (a_0, a_2, a_4, \ldots, a_{n-2}) \\
a_o & = (a_1, a_3, a_5, \ldots, a_{n-1}) \\
y_e & = \text{FFT}(a_e, n/2) \\
y_o & = \text{FFT}(a_o, n/2) \\
\text{for } k = 0 \text{ to } n/2 - 1 \text{ do} & \\
\quad y_k & = y_k^e + \omega \cdot y_k^o \\
\quad y_{k + n/2} & = y_k^e - \omega \cdot y_k^o \\
\quad \omega & = \omega \cdot \omega_n \\
\text{return } Y & \\
\end{array}
The algorithm splits the initial problem (polynomial of degree $n$) into two polynomials of half size and than does a recursion on the even and odd polynomes.
I know that the only way we can do the recursion is if we use roots of unity as our numbers.
I have 2 questions:
1.) What does this algorithm do at the bottom of the recursion?
2.)
I don't get what does the algorithm do in the last 4 lines of code?
I get that it has to combine the results, in order to get $Y$.
From the book Introduction to Algorithms, Cormen, on the page 890. it says that
$$y_k=A(\omega_n^k)$$
and
$$y_{k+\frac{n}{2}}=A(\omega_n^{k+\frac{n}{2}})$$
using some algebra.
So are those lines just constructing the elements of $Y$?
What is the purpose of the penultimate line of code $\omega=\omega \cdot \omega_n$?

Please ask only one question per post.

I think it is best to view the input of FFT not as an array, but as a polynomial, i.e. if $A = [a_0, a_1, \dots, a_{n-1}]$ for $n = 2^d$ this means we have the polynomial $p_A(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \dots + a_{n-1} x^{n-1}$. Now you can view $FFT(p_A)$ as the result of evaluating $p_A$ on all $n$-th roots of unity (i.e. numbers $\rho$ such that $\rho^n = 1$).
FFT now recursively splits $p_A$ in the even and odd coefficients such that
\begin{equation}p_A(x) = p_{A-even}(x^2) + x* p_{A-odd}(x^2)\end{equation}
These subpolynomials will be evaluated at the $\frac{n}{2}$-th roots of unity, since if $\rho$ is a $n$-th root of unity, then $\rho^2$ will be an $\frac{n}{2}$-th root of unity and by the formula above we only care about the values of the subpolynomials at the squares of a root of unity.
If the polynomial is constant, i.e. the array has length of one, then evaluating it is simple: just return the value.
The last four lines now recombine the solutions of the subproblems to get the resulting values. $\omega_n$ is the primitive $n$-th root of unity that means any root of unity can be represented as $\omega_n^i$ for some $i \in [0, n-1]$. Starting with $\omega=1= \omega_n^0$ we can generate with $\omega := \omega * \omega_n$ all $n$-th roots of unity. Since we want to evaluate $p_A$ we use the above formula.
The code above however does it a bit more clever. Since $n$ is, except for the base case, always an even number, we have that for any root of unity $\rho$ also $- \rho$ is a root of unity, but their square is the same. Hence we only have to generate $\frac{n}{2}$ many $n$-th roots of unity. Note that $- \rho = e^{i\pi} * \rho$ so that it's position is $\frac{n}{2}$ added to the index of the position of $\rho$ in $Y$.

FFT is hard.
Start with the original slow fourier transform which adds n^2 products. Interpret the numbers as complex numbers, which are each rotated by n different angles k * pi / 2^n.
FFT combines pairs of points rotated by pi / 2^n, then combines pairs rotated by 2pi / 2^n etc. The last lines perform a complex operation a + b rotated by 2^k * pi / 2^n.
